# Allow only certain character in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

http://jsbin.com/cunejafehe/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z\d\s\-'#(),"]*$/;
   
function myFunction(e){
  console.log(e.value);
  if(reg.test(e.value))
   {
     return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="myFunction(this)" type="text">
```

I wonder why above code doesn't work, what I want to do is allow only these character to be in the input : `a-z` and `1-9` including `0`, and these character `-'#(),"`

Comment: May be a `return true;` instead of `false`?

Comment: It works for me with `<input onkeypress="checkInput(event)" type="text">` and `var reg = /[a-zA-Z\d\s\-'#(),"]/;
  
function checkInput(e)
{
    var ok = reg.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    if (!ok)
        e.preventDefault();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this approach. Here i am passing an `event` object instead of DOM element reference and then we are checking it against Regx expression.

```js
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z\d\s\-'#(),"0-9]*$/
   
function myFunction(e){
  var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which)
  console.log(c);
  if(reg.test(c))
   {
     return true;
   }
 else
   return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#mytextbox" ).keypress(function( e) {
    return myFunction(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Inline function : <input onkeypress="return myFunction(event)" type="text">
<br/>

Binding a function : <input id="mytextbox" type="text">
```

Comment: what if I want to bind instead of using inline function? return on inline function look bad to me.

Comment: binding a keypress is also possible. You can do it like `$( "#mytextbox" ).keypress(function( e) {`

Comment: @AlienXu - updated the code snippet for binding instead of inline function.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` method belongs to a RegExp object, since you're not using that you should change `reg.test(c)` to `c.match(reg)` inside myFunction.

Moreover you are working on the full value of the field by passing `this`. I guess you can do something like this, even if not very elegant:

```js
 var reg = /^[a-zA-Z\d\s\-'#(),"]*$/;
 
function myFunction(e){
  if (!e.value.match(reg)) {
    e.value = e.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="myFunction(this)" type="text">
```

Comment: Edited the answer. I actually tested this and it works.

Comment: Yup... Now it works. Took the liberty to edit the question to test the code.